# What is the name of this surface? (resembles Boy's surface with holes)

Tags: geometry, surfaces

Does anyone know the name of this surface?  I feel like it has a particular name but can't seem to remember it for some reason.

[image]

Comment: I believe it's called "The glaring owl"

Comment: My friend suggested 'the mask'.

Comment: two hole torus,

Comment: Not sure, it must have some official name apart from that, it looks really distinctive.

Comment: It does have an official name, and Will Jagy has already stated it. This is just a two-hole torus, no matter how artistically it has been rendered.